# idMoneda property not updated in DB with @Transient directive

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this entity, in which I have made a PUT and POST method, which do not give an error but nevertheless the idMoneda, which is a property calculated with @Transient because it is the ID of the moneda(where there is a 1 to 1 relationship with another table), it does not update me, when I look at the database it remains null even though in the POST request I put a value. I don't know if it's because the setter is wrong, or just that something else needs to be added that I don't see right now.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REMESA")
public class Remesa {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "remesa_sequence", sequenceName = "remesa_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "remesa_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "moneda", nullable = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Moneda moneda;


    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("moneda")
    private Long idMoneda;

    public Long getIdMoneda() {
            return this.moneda.getId();
        }
    
        public void setIdMoneda(Long idMoneda) {
            this.idMoneda = idMoneda;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Transient` in JPA means: do not save this field in DB. A column named "moneda_id" will automatically be generated by your relationship if it's well-defined

Comment: Yes , i have a moneda_id column , but when i'm doing a POST or PUT doesn't add or update just place a NULL in the db at the moneda_id column

Answer (score 0):

Java's transient keyword is used to denote that a field is not to be serialized, whereas JPA's @Transient annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database, i.e. their semantics are different. Because they have different meanings.

So try to remove the transient annotation and run your code .

Comment: I did it , but now it's generating a new column called id_moneda instead moneda_id. And have 2 columns now